# Книги по Java

Tags: книги

Здравствуйте, посоветуйте пожалуйста хороших книжек по Java. Я конечно понимаю, такой вопрос задавался тысячу раз, и то, что программированию нельзя научиться по книгам, но все же надеюсь на ваше понимание. Спасибо.